# Fitting a largest area ellipse into a rectangle

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Given: a rectangle with vertices

$A(0,2), B(0.5, 2.5), C(2.5, -0.5)$ and $D(3,0)$.

How to find the largest ellipse that can fit inside this rectangle?I'm confused about this rotational angle that I need to find. I know that the procedure is like the one here https://xaktly.com/Ellipse.html but not sure about angle.

Comment: How do you define "largest"? area is largest? maybe you can start from a non-rotated case to maximize it, after you are done, then rotate it.

Comment: yup, but not sure about rotation @MathFail

Comment: *2.5 @coffeemath

Comment: There is an ellipse inside any rectangle (namely, the one with the axes being the segments connecting the midpoints of opposite sides of the rectangle). Is that ellipse the largest one inside the rectangle?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang: Yes.  See Intelligenti pauca's answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $OA$ and $OB$ be the semiaxes of the inscribed ellipse (see figure). The area of the ellipse is then:

$$\text{area}(\text{ellipse})=\pi\,OA\cdot OB.$$

If $T$ is a tangency point on side $QR$ of the rectangle, and $OG$ (parallel to $QR$) is the semidiameter conjugated to $OT$, then we know by Apollonius's theorem that:
$$
OA\cdot OB=2\,\text{area}(TOG)=2\,\text{area}(LOG)=OL\cdot OG,
$$
where $L$ is the midpoint of side $QR$. Hence:

$$\text{area}(\text{ellipse})=\pi\,OL\cdot OG.$$

As $OL$ is fixed, that area reaches its maximum when $OG$ is maximum, that is when $G$ is the midpoint of side $RS$. It follows that the inscribed ellipse with largest area is the one touching the sides of the rectangle at their midpoints.

[image]

EDIT.

To find the equation of this ellipse in your case, note first of all that its centre is $O=(1.5, 1)$ and its axes form an angle of $45°$ with coordinate axes, which implies $x\leftrightarrow y$ symmetry if centred at the origin. Hence the equation of the ellipse must be of the form:
$$
\alpha(x-1.5)^2+\alpha(y-1)^2+\beta(x-1.5)(y-1)=1,
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two constants, which can be easily found by plugging into the equation the coordinates of two tangency points, for instance $(0.25, 2.25)$ and $(1.75,1.25)$.

Comment: How do you get this last term of equation?

Comment: @Philip If the ellipse is centred at the origin, its general equation is a generic quadratic homogeneous polynomial, equated to $1$: $$\alpha x^2+\gamma y^2+\beta xy=1.$$ In our case, the symmetry $x\leftrightarrow y$ gives $\alpha=\gamma$. Compare also the very last formula at the page you linked, with $\theta=-45°$: you could directly use the expressions given there. For an ellipse centred at $(x_0, y_0)$, just replace $x$ with $(x-x_0)$ and $y$ with $(y-x_0)$.

Comment: you mean $y-y_0$

Comment: @Philip Yes, of course: it's a typo.

Comment: How did you find the angle?

Comment: @Philip The angle is obvious from the figure. But if you really want to spend some time on that, you can find the slope of the axes of the ellipse with the usual formulas.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the equation of an ellipse centered at the origin and aligned with the coordinate axes are:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are *half* the length and height, respectively.  To eliminate the annoying fractions, we can multiply by $a^2b^2$.

$$b^2x^2 + a^2y^2 = a^2b^2$$

Converting to polar coordinates, this is:

$$b^2r^2\cos^2(\theta) + a^2r^2\sin^2(\theta) = a^2b^2$$

Rotating the ellipse can be done simply by adding a constant adjustment to the angle.

$$b^2r^2\cos^2(\theta+\alpha) + a^2r^2\sin^2(\theta+\alpha) = a^2b^2$$

Or, applying the sum-of-angle identities:

$$b^2r^2(\cos\theta\cos\alpha - \sin\theta\sin\alpha)^2 + a^2r^2(\cos\theta\sin\alpha + \sin\theta\cos\alpha)^2 = a^2b^2$$
$$b^2r^2(\cos^2\theta\cos^2\alpha - 2 \cos\theta\sin\theta\cos\alpha\sin\alpha + \sin^2\theta\sin^2\alpha) + a^2r^2(\cos^2\theta\sin^2\alpha + 2\cos\theta\sin\theta\cos\alpha\sin\alpha + \sin^2\theta\cos^2\alpha) = a^2b^2$$

To convert back to rectangular coordinates, substitute $\cos\theta = \frac{x}{r}$ and $\sin\theta = \frac{y}{r}$, but leave the $\alpha$ parts alone.

$$b^2r^2((\frac{x}{r})^2\cos^2\alpha - 2 \frac{x}{r}\frac{y}{r}\cos\alpha\sin\alpha + (\frac{y}{r})^2\sin^2\alpha) + a^2r^2((\frac{x}{r})^2\sin^2\alpha + 2\frac{x}{r}\frac{y}{r}\cos\alpha\sin\alpha + (\frac{y}{r})^2\cos^2\alpha) = a^2b^2$$

$$b^2(x^2\cos^2\alpha - 2xy\cos\alpha\sin\alpha + y^2\sin^2\alpha) + a^2(x^2\sin^2\alpha + 2xy\cos\alpha\sin\alpha + y^2\cos^2\alpha) = a^2b^2$$

$$(a^2\sin^2\alpha + b^2\cos^2\alpha)x^2 + 2(a^2 - b^2)\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\ xy + (a^2\cos^2\alpha + b^2\sin^2\alpha)y^2 = a^2b^2$$

Note that if $\alpha = 0$, then $\cos\alpha = 1$ and $\sin\alpha = 0$, and the equation reduces to the original unrotated equation.

Finally, if the ellipse's center is shifted from the origin to the point $(x_0, y_0)$, then the equation becomes:

$$(a^2\sin^2\alpha + b^2\cos^2\alpha)(x - x_0)^2 + 2(a^2 - b^2)\cos\alpha\sin\alpha(x - x_0)(y - y_0) + (a^2\cos^2\alpha + b^2\sin^2\alpha)(y - y_0)^2 = a^2b^2$$

---

So now we have a generic equation for a rotated and shifted ellipse.  Let's apply it to your specific example.

Your rectangle is centered at the point (1.5, 1), and has side lengths of $\frac{5\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (AC and BD) and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (AB and CD).  Plugging in $x_0 = 1.5$, $y_0 = 1$, $a = \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{4}$, and $b = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$ gives:

$$(\frac{25}{8}\sin^2\alpha + \frac{1}{8}\cos^2\alpha)(x - x_0)^2 + 2(\frac{25}{8} - \frac{1}{8})\cos\alpha\sin\alpha(x - x_0)(y - y_0) + (\frac{25}{8}\cos^2\alpha + \frac{1}{8}\sin^2\alpha)(y - y_0)^2 = \frac{25}{8} \times \frac{1}{8}$$

$$(\frac{25}{8}\sin^2\alpha + \frac{1}{8}\cos^2\alpha)(x - \frac{3}{2})^2 + 6\cos\alpha\sin\alpha(x - \frac{3}{2})(y - 1) + (\frac{25}{8}\cos^2\alpha + \frac{1}{8}\sin^2\alpha)(y - 1)^2 = \frac{25}{64}$$

For the angle $\alpha$, note that the long sides of the rectangle (AC and BD) expressed as vectors are (2.5, -2.5) which, is at a 45° angle to the x axis.  So $\sin\alpha = \cos\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

$$(\frac{25}{8}\times\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8}\times\frac{1}{2})(x - \frac{3}{2})^2 + 3(x - \frac{3}{2})(y - 1) + (\frac{25}{8}\times\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8}\times\frac{1}{2})(y - 1)^2 = \frac{25}{64}$$
$$\frac{13}{8}(x - \frac{3}{2})^2 + 3(x - \frac{3}{2})(y - 1) + \frac{13}{8}(y - 1)^2 = \frac{25}{64}$$

As a sanity check on this equation, you can plug in the midpoints of the rectangle's sides — AB (0.25, 2.25), AC (1.25, 0.75), BD (1.75, 1.25), and CD (2.75, -0.25) — and confirm that all four lie on the ellipse.

If desired, you can expand the factors, multiply everything by 64 to get rid of the fractions, and rearrange the terms to get the equivalent equation

$$104x^2 + 192xy + 104y^2 - 504x - 496y + 601 = 0$$

Comment: Shouldn't $\alpha$ be $45°$?

Comment: Yeah, I think I calculated it wrong somehow.  Will fix it later.